Where to store shareable application data for home user?
I'm working on a project that uses ags (with gtk-layer-shell) to provide a top bar similar to waybar. I'm also building a gui app with pyGtk that'll be used to change that bar's appearance and settings.
Since I want this setup only to be available to the $home user I couldn't understand which directory should fit best. For example, if the bar uses a color scheme (css/json format) and I open my settings app it should first show me the current color scheme (means that data is shareable among the bar and the app) from where I can set a new one.
Other things include changing font size, bar position etc.
Currently I only have $home/.config/ags where I store the actual ags setup excluding any color scheme or default icons data.

The Free Desktop Standard is what many modern applications follow, especially those with desktop components.
This says (section 3)

$XDG_CONFIG_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user-specific configuration files should be stored. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.config should be used.
$XDG_STATE_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user-specific state files should be stored. If $XDG_STATE_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.local/state should be used.
The $XDG_STATE_HOME contains state data that should persist between (application) restarts, but that is not important or portable enough to the user that it should be stored in $XDG_DATA_HOME. It may contain:
actions history (logs, history, recently used files, …)
current state of the application that can be reused on a restart (view, layout, open files, undo history, …)

So for configuration data you should pick a directory under $XDG_CONFIG_HOME that matches your application name.

So I should put my config file in $home/.config/ags and shareable data (i.e. settings.json, colors.css etc.) in $home/.local/state/ags. Also is there something I can put in $home/.local/share?

No, you should use $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ags and only if that's not set should you use $HOME/.config/ags

I mean I've xdg directories set up but you said persistent data should be stored in $HOME/.local/state.  That's what I'm saying: config -> $HOME/.config/ags, data -> $HOME/.local/state

If I do export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/tmp then your program should write config to /tmp/ags.  If I do export XDG_STATE_HOME=/run/sweh then you should store state in /run/sweh/ags.   ONLY if these variables are not set should you use $HOME/.config/ags and so on.
